# How to do authentication for pages using angular2 and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a login page and 3 more pages along with that. Now i need to do authentication function. If the authentication is undefined then it must redirected to login page, if authentication is true it must go to checkLogin function. I am not getting how to do this but i had tried in this way,in one of the pages.

ts:

```
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class PageComponent implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') == undefined ) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
      else {
            /*Checklogin*/    
        this.ApiService
            .checklogin()
            .subscribe(
              user  => {}
      }
        }
```

but i get an error:

```
Class 'PageComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
    Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Observable<boolean> | Pr...'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
```

I dont know what i am doing is correct or not, can anyone guide me

Comment: you are not returning anything from the method

Comment: i have no idea how to do, i was trying this way, please can you suggest me how to do

Comment: `canActivate()` **must** return a value.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487827/how-to-apply-canactivate-guard-on-all-the-routes

Comment: without using canActivate() cant i do in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return 
`boolean or Observable<boolean> or Promise<boolean>` from `canActivate`

Also

`canActivate` should be something like this

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    //Your logic
}
```

Example

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') == undefined ) {
        return false; 
    }
  else {    
    return new Observable<boolean>((observer)=>{
        this.ApiService
        .checklogin()
        .subscribe((res)=>{
           //Check user
           if(condition){
              observer.next(true);
           }
           else{
             observer.next(false);
           }
           observer.complete();
        });
   });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i should write this function in other pages right?

Comment: Actually you should use canActivate with classes than components check this example https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/canactivate-and-canactivatechild

Comment: ya i will check, is there any other way for doing authentication, other than this method?

Answer (score 0):

`CanActivate` route guard expect a `boolean`, `Observable` or a `Promise` to be returned. Based on the value returned the page is authenticated.

In your case you can probably do something like this.

```
canActivate() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') == undefined ) {
    return false;
  }
  else {  
         return this.ApiService.checklogin()
      }
    }
```

In the implementation of `checklogin` you resolve/reject you promise/observable.

You can go through following article:
https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will try and update you @Amal