# Redirect all URLs with hash to Angular Routes without hash

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm replacing an existing AngularJS 1.6.x SPA with an Angular 5.x SPA and I want to make the change transparent to my users.

I'm concerned about users who have bookmarks to the existing app because it has hashes in the URLs (for example: `example.com/#/menu` and `example.com/#/item/37`);

However, the new app does not have hashes in the URLs (for example: `example.com/menu` and `example.com/item/37`).

The paths and routing are all the same, with the exception of the `#/` in the current app.

Is there a way I can configure the Angular routing to drop the  `#/` and use the hash-free routing configuration of the new app?

I could duplicate all of my routing to accommodate paths with and without the hash, but there must be a way that doesn't require doubling my code.

```
// Don't really want to do this:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuComponent
  },
  {
    path: '#/menu',
    component: MenuComponent
  },
  // etc.
];
```

Similarly, redirecting every `#/` path would double the code, too.

```
// Don't really want to do this:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuComponent
  },
  {
    path: '#/menu',
    redirectTo: 'menu'
  },
  // etc.
];
```

I'm hoping there is something along these lines:

```
{
  path: '#/*',
  redirectTo: '*' // Somehow reference the wildcard part of the path here 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: see this https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer posted by @Yanis *almost* worked, but required a few slight tweaks. His answer definitely deserves an upvote; however, below is the working solution I implemented:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/#/)) {
            this.router.navigate([event.url.replace('/#', '')]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but why do you use double negative !! ?

Comment: @awebdev - I use the double bang (!!) to cast truthy/falsey values into strict boolean types.

In my code, event.url is a string, while !!event.url is a boolean that is evaulated by the if statement. If there is a value for event.url, then !!event.url will be true, otherwise, it will be false if there is not a value.

See https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1784-using-double-not-operator-for-boolean-type-casting.htm

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I never took the time to learn why people use !!. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing - how did you handle 301s? Did you configure this in your server?

Comment: Won't SEO be affected unless a 301 status is returned?

Comment: This was for an internal corporate app, so I did not care about SEO. My only concern was saved bookmarks. But you're right to take SEO into consideration for a public facing app.

Comment: Note that this does not work if URL contains query string, like `/some/path?foo=1&bar=2`, because router encodes `?` and `&`. The `navigateByUrl` works better in this case: `this.router.navigateByUrl(event.url.replace('/#', ''));`.

Answer (score 11):

i don't know if is right way to do it. But you can do something like this : Goal is to subscribe to NavigationChange, then you check if your current route start by '#!', if yes, you redirect to the right route.

```
class AppComponent implement OnInit {
    constructor(router: Router) {
        //When url change, we check if actual url have #! on it, then we redirect to the route without it.
        router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent): void => {
            this.url = router.url;
            if (this.url.match('/^#!/')) {          
              this.router.navigate(
                this.url.replace('#!','')
              );
            }
          }
        );

    }
}
```

Another approch more complicated in my opinion is to use custom "matcher". More information here :

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12442

Answer (score 0):

Migrated an app from `HashLocationStrategy` to `PathLocationStrategy` and ended up doing this in `AppComponent` > `ngOnInit`:

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart && /^\/#/.test(event.url)))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => this.router.navigateByUrl(event.url.replace('/#', '')));
```

Note that `router.navigate` will strip any query params so I used `router.navigateByUrl` instead.

Once this is in place you can safely toggle `useHash` to `useHash: false` in your RoutingModule and both new and old URLs will continue working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `canActivate` guard to redirect to hash-free URLs when needed:

```js
export const hashRedirectGuard = () =>
  ((_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    const router = inject(Router);
    const url = state.url;
    const newUrl = '/' + trimStart(url, '/#');
    return url === newUrl || router.parseUrl(newUrl);
  }) satisfies CanActivateFn;

// app-routing.module.ts
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [hashRedirectGuard()], // Wrap all routes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43487962/12292636
    children: [...],
  }
];
```