# Hash (#) in URL - Angular

Tags: angular, url, hash-location-strategy

I have an Angular 14 application that uses **HashLocationStrategy** - **#** in URL (Example: https://localhost:4200/#/agenda?data=2023-03-22).

Some of my customers have tried to post stories on Instagram, but Instagram "cuts" the URL from the hash (#), leaving it as https://localhost:4200/.

I would like to switch to **PathLocationStrategy**, without the hash (Example: https://localhost:4200/agenda?data=2023-03-22).

However, I already have many customers who use the URL WITH HASH.

**Is it possible to make my application accept URLs with and without hash?**

Or another solution?

Thank you.

My application accept URLs with and without hash.

Comment: I guess a url with hash would match an empty route, basically home? If so, you could have a listener there that checks for a hash in the url and reroute the customer to the correct path? That’s what I would try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A LocationStrategy used to configure the Location service to represent its state in the hash fragment of the browser's URL.

So this means: You can't. Its a injected Service and you cannot change it on runtime. But what you can do is the follow:

My opinion is: Do not mix it. But if you must do it, here is a solution:

**In your App Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (!!event.url && event.url.match(/^\/#/)) {
            this.router.navigate([event.url.replace('/#', '')]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

The original Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534503/4472932). With this code you can replace the **#**, or not. What you want.

#### Note... I know..

I know that looks a little hacky at first. But there is no way (and if so there is no good way) to change the `LocationStrategy` in Angular dynamically in runtime.

Comment: Thank you Flo! By the way, is it possible to do this redirection via Apache configuration? Would it be a better solution?

Comment: I‘m not a Apache expert. But I think yes, you can do it, too if you wanna only replace it.