# Validate URL Parameters on Every Route Change and Redirect

Tags: angular, url-routing

I'm working on an application where most URLs starts with a couple of dynamic parameters. Something like this:

```
https://projects/:projectId/:subProjectId/<service>/..
```

However, currently there is no validation of these IDs and I am looking for a proper way to intercept, validate and re-route (if not valid) on every navigation change. Basically I want to parse the URL (using `route.paramMap` or similar), query the backend DB to check if the IDs exists and re-route to a "Not Found" page if they do not.

I know there are several ways to check for a route change, but I am not sure what the proper approach is for this case. I could subscribe to a routing event or do something like:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="changeOfRoute()"></router-outlet>
```

This does not feel correct however as I am not really intercepting the route change and validating/redirecting before the navigation starts. I could also use a route resolver:

```
resolve: { resolver: IdValidationResolverService}
```

This is not very practical as I would need to ensure the resolver is used on every route and it's children instead of having something global that applies to every navigation change.

I could use some input on the correct way of handling this.

Comment: angular guards are useful to check navigation between routes. You can try to look into them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply canActivate guard on all the routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487827/how-to-apply-canactivate-guard-on-all-the-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `Guard`, for example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IdValidatorGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

 canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
 ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | 
UrlTree {
const id = next.paramMap.get('id');
return this.http.get(`api/validateId/${id}`).pipe(
  map(result => {
    if (result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/404']);
      return false;
    }
  })
);
}
}
```